# How can I properly set up the OpenID extension for Media Wiki so users can only register with that?

Tags: openid, mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions

I made a Media Wiki site, eatwiki.org, and because mandatory account creation was not enabled by default it was heavily spammed. I installed an extension that has a math captcha to try to stop it, but the spam bots just made many accounts. I disabled account creation and installed the OpenID extension, but because account creation is disabled, users cannot make a username when creating an account with OpenID, which means they cannot create an account at all.

How can I make it so normal account creation is off, but users can create a username when creating an account with OpenID?

To me this seems to be the only option because if account creation is on, even if there is a captcha, spam bots will create many accounts.

I added this to LocalSettings.php to disable normal account creation:

```
$wgGroupPermissions['*']['createaccount'] = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and it seems that this situation is not currently handled by the OpenID plugin. I installed a second plugin, [Confirm Account](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aConfirmAccount), which gives wiki admins the power to accept or reject user account requests.